# Captura de error en un JSON con valores incorrectos (Java)

Tags: java, json, jsonobject, try-catch

Buenas he estado buscando la forma de capturar el error en un `JSON` con valores inválidos esto en `Java`.
Bueno yo se como leer cada uno de estos valores de forma correcta lo que pasa es cuando este esta escrito de forma incorrecta dentro del JSON.

Ejemplo de un JSON correcto:

```
{ "Object" : "Merchant",
  "ID" : 50,
  "Name" : "Lucia",
  "Height" : 0.7,
}
```

Ejemplo de JSON incorrecto:

```
{ "Object" : "Merchant",
  "ID" : 50,
  "Name" : Lucia,
  "Height" : 0.7s,
}
```

Ahora como ven si yo intento de leer la key `"Name"` lo haría con `jsonObject.get("Name")`, como pueden ver al este estar escrito sin las comillas no lo detecta como un `String` entonces lo que quiero es detectar esto para capturar el error.

Lo mismo pasa si intento `jsonObject.get("Height")` como este termina con un carácter no numeral entonces me tira un error.

En resumen lo único que quiero es detectar es cuando un `value` de un `key` es incorrecto.
Esto lo quiero hacer en caso de que el usuario edite el `JSON` manualmente y pongan por error un valor donde no corresponde.

Comment: normalmente los frameworks con los que conviertes a objeto se encargan por ti, muchos de dichos frameworks usas un json object asi que sin los imports solo poriamos adivinar como ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

muy importante esas validaciones, muchas personas no la tienen en cuenta y se cometen graves errores.

No solo que venga mal construido, sino que exista texto fuera del JSON como alertas u errores del comilador. ej:

```
"invalid argument supplied for foreach()"
{ "Object" : "Merchant",
  "ID" : 50,
  "Name" : "Lucia",
  "Height" : 0.7,
}
```

Esto destruye la estructura por completo.
Para eso, puedes usar "try"

Este ejemplo es para tomar un JSON y tratar de convertirlo a un String.

```
var myJSON = '';
try {
  myJSON = JSON.stringify({ "Object" : "Merchant", "ID" : 50, "Name" : "Lucia", "Height" : 0.7, });
} catch (error) {
  console.error('JSON invalid format');
}

if(myJSON != '') ...continue
```

De la misma manera si tienes un String y deseas pasarlo a un arreglo.

```
var myJSON = [];
try {
  myJSON = JSON.parse('{ "Object" : "Merchant", "ID" : 50, "Name" : "Lucia", "Height" : 0.7, }');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('JSON string invalid format');
}

if(myJSON.length > 0) ...continue
```

Comment: Bueno la cuestión es que es en `Java` y no en `JavaScript` e intente con `try` previamente a formular la pregunta, pero no encontré la forma de hacerlo funcionar y por mas que pusiera la lectura del `key` dentro de un `try` seguía ejecutando la línea, cuando debería pasar a ejecutar el `catch`.

Comment: Oh, srry, mi error, leí mal tu pregunta.

Comment: Para nada compañero, esto puede ayudar alguna persona que este buscando esto pero para `JavaScript` y además me queda de aprendizaje para mi mismo y por si algún día me toca hacerlo con `JavaScript`.
Además decidí hacer con una escritura y lectura propia. Mientras que doy con la solución de esto puedo hacerlo de esta manera. De todas formas la lectura y escritura se hace por una sola vía por lo que puedo cambiar la forma en que se efectúa de forma libre.